# How to get access to a wordpress plugin data?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress-rest-api

I am facing a problem with `phpmyadmin` data. Actually, what I am trying to do is to create a `JSON API` so that I can synchronize my website’s data with the android application which I have already developed.However,the problem I am facing is that inside the `phpmyadmin` board some of the data appear as `NULL` .As a result the form of the data appears as `NULL` in the `JSON API` as well.I would like to know ,if it is possible ,how I could get access to those data that appear  with the indication `NULL` in order for them to be transferred in their original form e.g text… Here is the `JSON API` I created: [JSON API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdCxU.png)

Here is the phpmyadmin data: [phpmyadmin data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17gkX.png)

And here is the activity post, that's what I am trying to get from the data: [Activity post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXawy.png)

Does anyone know how can I get access to those data?

##### Edit 1:

```json
{
   "act_id":1,
   "act_external_id":525,
   "act_module_id":"127.0.0.1",
   "act_link_image_id":0,
   "act_description":null
}
```

And I want to get this:

```json
{
   "act_id":1,
   "act_external_id":525,
   "act_module_id":"127.0.0.1",
   "act_link_image_id":0,
   "act_description":"Hello World!"
}
```

Comment: If you have NULL in pma, how do you want the data in api? It's likely that this data is stored in a different table - that's why you have it somewhere else. (because you don't write them correctly)

Comment: @bato3 But, there is no other table for the activity posts. That's why I thought there would be a way to turn the data from NULL to the original format.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the question. Can you give an example of *what you get* and an example: *what do you want to get*?  [As code](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: @bato3 Of course. I get this: 
`{
  "act_id": 1,
  "act_external_id": 525,
  "act_module_id": "127.0.0.1",
  "act_link_image_id": 0,
  "act_description": null
}` And I want to get this: `{
  "act_id": 1,
  "act_external_id": 525,
  "act_module_id": "127.0.0.1",
  "act_link_image_id": 0,
  "act_description": "Hello World!"
}`

Comment: Show me `Hello World!` in PMA data https://i.stack.imgur.com/17gkX.png I Don't see it...

Comment: @bato3 well, that's what I am trying to figure out. I can't find the `Hello World!` inside the table. I searched on the rest tables and it is nowhere. That's what I want to figure out.

Comment: Let's clarify: **Do you see `Hello World` elsewhere?** -> Data is taken from elsewhere, e.g. manually overwritten (`if ($field == NULL) return 'Hello World!'`). **There is no data anywhere** -> data has not been saved correctly. (Wrong format, no `commit`) ***Try to add directly*** in PMA, check for errors when adding in API.

Comment: @bato3 Alright, I see. Thank you for your help. I understood what is the problem.